# IOS open in works on simulator crashes on device with UIPopoverController error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

In storyboard I have a view controller that displays pdf files if other apps try to `"open in"` with my app.

In simulator  IOS 5.1 or IOS 6 + , it works perfectly but on device I get `SIGABRT`  on main thread with this error:

```
[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'
```

Bizarre thing I dont have any `UIPopoverController` in related viewcontrollers.

In find I search "UIPopoverController" and none of the related controllers (offlinereader,leftSideMenuViewController,navigationController) has a popovercontroller

```
#pragma OpeIn
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
           openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation
{
    // Make sure url indicates a file (as opposed to, e.g., http://)
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
        NSLog(@"Url in app delegate= %@",url);


        UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                     bundle:nil];
        OfflineReaderViewController *registerVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OfflineReaderViewController"];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        registerVC.filePath=url;
        self.viewController = registerVC;

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

        // Tell our OfflineReaderViewController to process the URL
        [self.viewController handleDocumentOpenURL:url];

    }
    // Indicate that we have successfully opened the URL
    return YES;
}

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UITabBarController *navigationController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];
        [MFSideMenu menuWithNavigationController:navigationController
                          leftSideMenuController:leftSideMenuViewController
                         rightSideMenuController:nil];

     return YES;

    }
```

offlinereader is `: UIViewController<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>`

Whats going on?
How can I solve or find the exact problem?

**EDIT::::**
Full error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x317932a3 0x3962997f 0x317931c5 0x33986d5f 0x338d7285 0x338d7b35 0xe49cf 0xe51a5 0x335ba595 0x33603fd7 0x33603f45 0x336884ef 0x33686fe7 0x51bb3 0x3376bb33 0x33744881 0x33743f6b 0x3359bd59 0x3359b6cd 0x3359b11b 0x3528f5a3 0x31768683 0x31767ee9 0x31766cb7 0x316d9ebd 0x316d9d49 0x3528e2eb 0x335ef301 0x50c89 0x50c10)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SIGABRT` errors are helpful follow this tutorial and find your exact line with problem.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

When you find the problem , there must be definetly related some popover code in your breakpoint line

If so add this

```
if (self.view.window != nil) {
    //your popover code
}
```

Above code just basically checks if there is a window is present, duh run the code.